# CodeFluent Template sample from blog not updating

Tags: templates, codefluent

I've been following the post https://blog.codefluententities.com/2013/03/20/generate-asp-net-web-api-controllers-using-template/ to generate a web.api service.

First building of the model is working OK but building again after some improvements done, doesn't update the target project Controller file.

I've also checked the "Target Project Layout"property to be "Update" on the template producer but isn't working even.

Comment: You have to set `productionFlags="Overwrite"` to overwrite an existing file (https://www.softfluent.com/documentation/ProducerConcepts_ChangingTheProductionBehavior.html)

Comment: Tried this and overwrite="true" in project xml template producer section but controller files in web.api project are not overwritten.

Comment: You can find additional build information in the `<project>.build.xml` file. This can be helpful to diagnose the issue.